# How to make the right PHP version on my terminal?

Tags: php, macos, macos-mojave

When i run the command 'which php' in terminal, i get this answer :

```
/usr/bin/php
```

When i run 'php -v', i get :

```
PHP 7.1.19 (cli) (built: Aug 17 2018 18:03:17) ( NTS )
```

This is the bundled PHP in MacOS Mojave.

But i actually installed other version (7.2.9), that is currently running on Apache, confirmed by phpinfo(). It's on the folder :

/usr/local/php5-7.2.9-20180821-074958

How can make the terminal use the active version instead of the one bundled in MacOs ?

I want when i run anything from the terminal, it uses the 7.2.9 version.

Thanks

Comment: Have you corrected this? I'm facing the same sitution. I didn't get the appropriate answer from the other mentioned thread. Can you please help me on this.

Comment: @chithra I'm very sorry, but now i don't remember what exactly i did to fix that. I think i installed a new php version and ended up not using the one that came with Mojave